# MySQL - Merge or split datetime intervals (start date to end date)

Tags: mysql, datetime, interval

I have a table which stores a list of activities with an interval of time delimited by 2 dates.

Sample:

```
+------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
| name |        start        |         end         | time (calc) |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
|  me  | 2017-04-03 11:00:00 | 2017-04-03 11:30:00 |          30 |
|  me  | 2017-04-03 23:45:00 | 2017-04-04 00:15:00 |          30 |
|  me  | 2017-04-04 10:00:00 | 2017-04-04 11:00:00 |          60 |
|  me  | 2017-04-04 10:30:00 | 2017-04-04 11:30:00 |          60 |
|  me  | 2017-04-05 23:00:00 | 2017-04-05 23:30:00 |          30 |
|  me  | 2017-04-05 23:15:00 | 2017-04-07 00:45:00 |        1530 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
```

I would like to know how many minutes are occupied each day per user (and then per week), so I need to transform current table into where intervals which share a partial space time are merged in a single one, and intervals which are in several days are split, like the next one:

```
+------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
| name |        start        |         end         | time (calc) |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
|  me  | 2017-04-03 11:00:00 | 2017-04-03 11:30:00 |          30 |
|  me  | 2017-04-03 23:45:00 | 2017-04-03 23:59:59 |          15 |
|  me  | 2017-04-04 00:00:00 | 2017-04-04 00:15:00 |          15 |
|  me  | 2017-04-04 10:00:00 | 2017-04-04 11:30:00 |          90 |
|  me  | 2017-04-05 23:00:00 | 2017-04-05 23:59:59 |          60 |
|  me  | 2017-04-06 00:00:00 | 2017-04-06 23:59:59 |        1440 |
|  me  | 2017-04-07 00:00:00 | 2017-04-07 00:45:00 |          45 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
```

To then query it easily in order to obtain minutes per day:

```
+------+------------+------+
| name |    day     | time |
+------+------------+------+
|  me  | 2017-04-03 |   45 |
|  me  | 2017-04-04 |  105 |
|  me  | 2017-04-05 |   60 |
|  me  | 2017-04-06 | 1440 |
|  me  | 2017-04-07 |   45 |
+------+------------+------+
```

I were looking for information an I found how to merge multiple date intervals here ([mysql - sum interval dates](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80789)), however I am not able to split an interval in several days.

It is possible to do it in a single query? How could I do it?

**Edit:**

SQL (structure and data):

```
CREATE TABLE activities (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(45),
    start DATETIME,
    end DATETIME,
    time INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start, end)) VIRTUAL
);

INSERT INTO activities (name, start, end) VALUES
('me','2017-04-03 11:00','2017-04-03 11:30'),
('me','2017-04-03 23:45','2017-04-04 00:15'),
('me','2017-04-04 10:00','2017-04-04 11:00'),
('me','2017-04-04 10:30','2017-04-04 11:30'),
('me','2017-04-05 23:00','2017-04-05 23:30'),
('me','2017-04-05 23:15','2017-04-07 00:45');
```

SQL to merge multiple intervals (Soruce: [mysql - sum interval dates](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80789)):

```
SELECT name, min(start) AS start, end, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(start), end) AS time
FROM (
    SELECT x.name, x.start, min(y.end) AS end 
    FROM activities AS x 
    JOIN activities AS y 
        ON x.name = y.name 
       AND x.start <= y.end 
       AND NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT 1 
           FROM activities AS z 
           WHERE y.name = z.name 
             AND y.end >= z.start 
             AND y.end < z.end
       ) 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM activities AS u 
        WHERE x.name = u.name 
          AND x.start > u.start 
          AND x.start <= u.start
    ) 
    GROUP BY x.name, x.start
) AS v GROUP BY name, end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First due you need to generate a series of dates, I'd suggest to use a `calendar` table.

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists calendar (
    mdate date PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO calendar values
('20170403'),('20170404'),('20170405'),('20170406'),('20170407'),('20170408');
```

**How do they do it**

Just to get overlapped activities I've used the query that you provided on your question.

```
create view overlaped_activities
as
SELECT name, min(start) AS start, end, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(start), end) AS time
FROM (
    SELECT x.name, x.start, min(y.end) AS end 
    FROM activities AS x 
    JOIN activities AS y 
        ON x.name = y.name 
       AND x.start <= y.end 
       AND NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT 1 
           FROM activities AS z 
           WHERE y.name = z.name 
             AND y.end >= z.start 
             AND y.end < z.end
       ) 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM activities AS u 
        WHERE x.name = u.name 
          AND x.start > u.start 
          AND x.start <= u.start
    ) 
    GROUP BY x.name, x.start
) AS v GROUP BY name, end;
```

First I calculate minutes from start date till midnight:

```
if(date(start) = date(end), 
  time_to_sec(timediff(end, start)) / 60, 
  (1440 - time_to_sec(time(start)) / 60)) mstart
```

Then, if start <> end, I calculate minutes from midnight till end date:

```
if(date(start) = date(end), 0, time_to_sec(time(end)) / 60) mend
```

This returns a table like this:

```
| start               | end                 |     mdiff |  mstart |    mend |
|---------------------|---------------------|----------:|--------:|--------:|
| 03.04.2017 11:00:00 | 03.04.2017 11:30:00 |   30,0000 | 30,0000 |       0 |
| 03.04.2017 23:45:00 | 04.04.2017 00:15:00 |   30,0000 | 15,0000 | 15,0000 |
| 04.04.2017 10:00:00 | 04.04.2017 11:30:00 |   90,0000 | 90,0000 |       0 |
| 05.04.2017 23:00:00 | 07.04.2017 00:45:00 | 1545,0000 | 60,0000 | 45,0000 |
```

That's nice, but there is another problem here:

```
| 05.04.2017 23:00:00 | 07.04.2017 00:45:00 | 1545,0000 | 60,0000 | 45,0000 |
```

Of course: `1545 <> 60 + 45`

We need to generate a series of dates between start and end date, and add 1440 minutes to each day.

We can get it using the calendar table:

```
   select   name,
            mdate date_activity,
            sum(1440) minutes
   from     calendar
   join     overlaped_activities
   on       calendar.mdate > date(start)
   and      calendar.mdate < date(end)
   where    datediff(end, start) > 1
   group by name, mdate
```

Ok, we got all ingredients, it's time to cook the recipe:

```
select name, date_activity, sum(minutes) min_activity
from (
       select name, 
              date(start) date_activity,
              if(date(start) = date(end), time_to_sec(timediff(end, start)) / 60, (1440 - time_to_sec(time(start)) / 60)) minutes
       from overlaped_activities

       UNION ALL

       select name, 
              date(end) date_activity,
              if(date(start) = date(end), 0, time_to_sec(time(end)) / 60) minutes
       from overlaped_activities

       UNION ALL

       select   name,
                mdate date_activity,
                sum(1440) minutes
       from     calendar
       join     overlaped_activities
       on       calendar.mdate > date(start)
       and      calendar.mdate < date(end)
       where    datediff(end, start) > 1
       group by name, mdate
    ) act
group by name, date_activity;
```

Final result:

```
| name |       date_activity | min_activity |
|------|--------------------:|-------------:|
| me   | 03.04.2017 00:00:00 |      45,0000 |
| me   | 04.04.2017 00:00:00 |     105,0000 |
| me   | 05.04.2017 00:00:00 |      60,0000 |
| me   | 06.04.2017 00:00:00 |    1440,0000 |
| me   | 07.04.2017 00:00:00 |      45,0000 |
```

Almost forget it, the recipe: http://rextester.com/EIJOI20983

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, to split the across days, we need to join with the table having dates as Oracle feature of Connect by level is not supported in MySQL.

Adding more details...

```
Create table ActivityDay 
(id INT Primary Key NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ActivityDay Date NOT NULL);

insert into ActivityDate (ActivityDay) values('2017-04-03'), 
values('2017-04-04'),values('2017-04-05'),
values('2017-04-06'),values('2017-04-07'),
values('2017-04-08');

Select id, Name, ActualStart, ActualEnd, 
(Time_to_Sec(ActualEnd) - Time_to_Sec(ActualStart))/60 time
from (
select a.id, a.name, a.start, Date(start) StartDay, Date(end) EndDay, a.time,
       case when DATE(START) = DATE(ActualStart) then Start else ActivityDay end ActualStart,
       case when Date(end) <> Date(ActualEnd) then date_add(ActivityDay, interval 24*60*60 - 1 second) else end end ActualEnd,
       ad.ActivityDay
from Activities a join ActivityDate ad) d
Where ActivityDay between start and end)
```

Comment: Something is wrong in the "CASE" columns (case when DATE(START) = DATE(ActualStart) then Start else ActivityDay end ActualStart, case when Date(end) <> Date(ActualEnd) then date_add(ActivityDay, interval 24*60*60 - 1 second) else end end ActualEnd).

You are using "ActualStart" to define "ActualStart".

Comment: The problem is the `else end end`, not in `ActualStart`, I think. A problem which would have been avoided @vgc, if you had not used reserved keywords as column names.

Comment: I am receiving "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'ActualStart' in 'field list'", because it is using it to define itself. As well as in `WHERE ActivityDay BETWEEN start AND end;` "start" and "end" does not exists at that level.

Comment: What's the `id` column in `ActivityDay` for?

Answer (score 0):

If it's just split by dates and you're using DATETIME, it can be quite simple. Just substring the timestamp and group by the date

```
SELECT
who,
SUBSTRING(date_created, 1, 10) AS date,
COUNT(times) AS time
FROM timings
WHERE date_created > '2017-04-03' AND date_created < '2017-04-10'
GROUP BY date
```

```
+------+------------+------+
| name |    day     | time |
+------+------------+------+
|  me  | 2017-04-03 |   45 |
|  me  | 2017-04-04 |  105 |
|  me  | 2017-04-05 |   60 |
|  me  | 2017-04-06 | 1440 |
|  me  | 2017-04-07 |   45 |
+------+------------+------+
```